# MVC DbContext pull out all model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using Database first method. EDMX file generated default Dbset(TableName) for me.

```
myDbContext.Table1.ToList();
myDbContext.Table2.ToList();
```

Can we have a ModelView Class which pull both table out with single line?
Instead of

```
Table1=myDbContext.Table1.ToList();
Table2=myDbContext.Table2.ToList();
```

can we have like

```
ModelView=myDbContext.ModelView;
```

**Updated**

```
  public partial class ProductTb
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

}

  public partial class ProductTbTWO
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

}

  public class ProductModelView
{
   public ProductTb{get;set;}
public ProductTbTWO{get;set}

}
```

Comment: Only if you project both tables to the same view model.

Comment: Can you explain? Assuming both are in the same view Model now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i prefer using static class:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static ProductModelView getProductViewModel()
    {
        using (var db = new myDbContext()
        {
            var vm = new ProductModelView();
            vm.ProductTb = db.ProductTb.ToList();
            vm.ProductTbTWO = db.ProductTbTWO.ToList();
            return vm;
        }
    }
}
```

you can call it like:

```
var vm = Utilities.getProductViewModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Partial Class of your DbContext and add your custom Code.

```
public partial  class MyDbContext 
{
   private MyDbContext(string contextName) : base(contextName) { }

   public static MyDbContextCreate() {
      return new MyDbContext(ContextName);
   }

   public ProductModelView ModelView {// Get ProductTb and ProductTbTWO}
}
```

and use it `var myDbContext= MyDbContext.Create()` and `myDbContext.ModelView`

> But I don't recommend to do something like that, Add a Service class to with public method to get your code, Data Layer shouldn't deal with View Models